# Pass a PHP variable to another file

Tags: php, variables

Is there a simple method to passing data from one file to another? I'm new to PHP and can't find a simple answer to my problem online. Apologies if this has been answered a million times & thanks in advance.

```
My Template 

<?php

// Declare a variable with the name of the file I want to pull in 
$critical_css = 'style';

// Header
get_header();

?>
```

```
Header 

// Get php file with inline style written inside
<?php get_template_part('/path/to/' . $critical_css); ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WordPress template functions don't support passing variables (to my knowledge) by default, so you need to write your own function. For example like this,

```
// functions.php
function my_template_include_with_variables( string $path = '', $data = null ) {
  $file = get_template_directory() . '/' . $path . '.php';
  if ( $path && file_exists( $file ) ) {
    // $data variable is now available in the other file
    include $file;
  }  
}

// in a template file
$critical_css = 'style';
// include header.php and have $critical_css available in the template file
my_template_include_with_variables('header', $critical_css);

// in header.php
var_dump($data); // should contain whatever $critical_css had
```

---

**UPDATE 18.8.2020**

Since [WordPress 5.5](https://wordpress.org/news/2020/08/eckstine/) you are able to pass additional arguments with the native template functions (e.g. [get_header()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/), [get_template_part()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/), etc.) to the template files in an array.

From dev docs,

> get_template_part( string $slug, string $name = null, array $args =
> array() )

Answer (score 3):

Simply declaring your variable as [global](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) in your header template will suffice:

```php
<?php

global $critical_css;
get_template_part('/path/to/' . $critical_css);

?>
```

No need to write your own template loading stuff (which usually is a bad idea).

Comment: I think "polluting" the `global` space like this is considered bad practice

Comment: Wouldn't 'global' need to be written in the template where the the variable is first defined? 

```
global  $critical_css = 'cc-frontpage';

```

neither work unfortunately :(

Comment: @kero It's WordPress. The global namespace already is a radioactive soup. There are of course more "elegant" solutions, but sometimes this is overkill and certainly out of scope here.

Comment: @EvanMeredith-Davies This works. Tested it in a vanilla WordPress installation. `global` needs to be used in the file/place where you want to _access_ the variable, not where you _define_ it. Your second code snippet, which file exactly is this in?

Answer (score 0):

use this to define your global variable

```
function turn_addons_vars() {
    // Your Variable Names
    global $kdev_addons,  $kdev_addon;
    // Set Default your variable Data
    $critical_css = '';
    $kdev_addon = '';
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'turn_addons_vars' );
```

in anywhere you can use global for example:

a.php:

```
global $critical_css; 
$critical_css = "style";
```

b.php:

```
global $critical_css; 
get_template_part('/path/to/' . $critical_css);
```

if you are access to `functions.php` or develop a theme. you can instead use : [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/353442/191341](/questions/353441/pass-a-php-variable-to-another-file/353442#353442)